# javascript performance: global variable vs jquery's $.data()

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I need to store relatively larget bit of JSON for global access in my web app.

Should I use jquery's `$.data(document.body, 'some-reference-here', MyJsonObj);` or a global?

I know binding $.data() to document.body is faster than to a jquery object, but how does this compare to global variable?

I'm interested the most efficient memory usage.

Comment: Woah, watch out son, those 2ms speed differences will make your application way too fast. Dont pre optimize, and when you do optimize, profile first and start with the slowest part.

Comment: I'm working on a mobile web-app, where the device's memory is in real short supply...

Comment: @Petah funny - I got flamed last week for daring to suggest that a 2ms page setup lag was fine when a harder-to-understand version could do it a hundred times faster...

Comment: @Haroldo using `$.data()` will result in a negligible amount of extra memory compared to a global variable, since ultimately all that `$.data()` does is store a _reference_ to a variable (which could even be your global) in a DOM element.

Comment: Thanks Alnitak. I'll leave it as a global then...

Comment: @Haroldo it would be better to find some way to not put that variable in global scope, though.  Global variables are bad!

Comment: I don't think memory related to the access method is the issue, the footprint size is much more correlated to the amount of data than how it is accessed. Performance may be worth considering, direct property access is very much faster than via a function call. The impact of a one global variable would be irrelevant in any comparison of the two approaches. If memory is *that* critical, why are you using jQuery?

Comment: @RobG - Yes, unfortunately using jquery for quick developement. My plan being to revisit later when I have more time and code in pure js or a smaller library like zeptos.js....

Comment: @Alnitak Doesn't `data` serialize have to serialize objects to put them into `data-` attributes?

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko it doesn't appear to - I just tested Chrome and an HTML data attribute would set the _initial_ value of `.data()` but changes to that data did not then appear in the HTML data attribute.

Comment: @Alnitak That's interesting to know!

Answer (score 7):

Global variable in browser JS means `window.variable`, so I think it would be much faster then 
`$.data(document.body, 'some-reference-here', MyJsonObj);` just because this is only one touch of the object's property instead of function call, getting property of document and much staff inside of the data call. But another problem is polluting global scope. Maybe it's better to store this data somewhere inside the local scope of your script.